# Mass conservation for heat equation with Neumann conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab

I'm trying to implement Neumann boundary conditions to solve the heat equation with an explicit scheme. I checked mass conservation, but it doesn't seem to hold. Could someone check if my boundary conditions are correctly implemented?

The equation to be computed on the interval $[0,1]$ is:

$$m_t=\nu\Delta m$$ with $m(\cdot,0)=m(\cdot,1)=0$ and the initial condition is Gaussian.

In discretised form:

$$m^{i+1}_j=m^i_j+p(m_{j+1}^i-2m_j^i+m_{j-1}^i)$$ where $p=\nu\frac{dt}{h^2}$. For the BC I used $$\frac{m_1^i-m_{-1}^i}{h^2}=0\quad \text{so}\quad m_1^i=m_{-1}^i$$ and hence $$m_0^{i+1}=m_0^i+2p(m_1^i-m_0^i)$$ So I want to solve: $$m^{i+1}=Am^i$$ where A is the matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix}
  1-2p & 2p & 0 &  & \cdots& 0 \\
p & 1-2p& p && \\
  0 & p & 1-2p  &p &\cdots&0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots& \ddots & \ddots &\vdots  \\
& && p & 1-2p&p\\
  0 & 0 & \cdots& 0& 2p&1-2p 
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Here's the Matlab code

```
N=15; M=5; 
nu=0.07;

dt=1/(N+1); h=1/(M+1);
p=nu*dt/h^2;

A=eye(M+1) + p * ( diag(ones(M,1),-1) - 2*diag(ones(M+1,1),0) + diag(ones(M,1),1) );

A(1,2)=2*p; A(end,end-1)=2*p; 
mk=zeros(N+1,M+1);
%initial condition
sigma=0.07;
x2=linspace(0,1,M+1);
mk(1,:)=1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)*exp(-(x2-0.5).^2/(2*sigma^2));
for i=1:N
    mk(i+1,:)=A*mk(i,:)';
end

sum(mk,2)
```

The output is

```
    4.1097
    4.1099
    4.2142
    4.3373
    4.4505
    4.5464
    4.6257
    4.6895
    4.7428
    4.7836
    4.8155
    4.8423
    4.8624
    4.8793
    4.8884
    4.8993
```

so mass doesn't seem to be conserved.

I would appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: Maybe you just have your rows and columns wrong – are you sure you don't want `mk(i+1,:)=A.'*mk(i,:).';` or, more simply, `mk(i+1,:)=mk(i,:)*A;`?

Comment: Typo alert - your matrix $A$ is the matrix you wrote down, not the identity matrix plus the matrix you wrote down.

Comment: Also in your code, I think you should have $dt=1/N$ and $h=1/M$.  Not that it makes any difference to your problem - it just means that your value for $\nu$ is slightly different than you thought.

Comment: @horchler No I don't think that is correct. This was the Neumann condition is not satisfied. I want to multiply the matrix by a column vector.

Answer (score 3):

Your scheme will preserve the mass when it is computed by the trapezoidal rule:
$$ \text{mass}(i) = \tfrac12(m^i_0 + m^i_M) + \sum_{j=1}^{M-1} m^i_j .$$
One way to see this is that if $w = [0.5,1,\dots,1,0.5]$, then $w A = w$.  Hence $w\cdot m^{i+1} = w A m^{i} = w \cdot m^{i}$.

Comment: Is it possible that what I am observing is only due to numerical error, because the scheme is only first order? If I decrease the final time to 0.1, the total mass still decreases but by much less. Also if I increase M beyond a certain point, the solution becomes unstable and rapidly oscillates.

Comment: The latter is because the CFL condition is not satisfied anymore.

Comment: No, there is no way that what you are observing is due to numerical error.  Try doing a much smaller example by hand, maybe with $M=2$, with exact arithmetic, and unless you are very unlucky with your choice of initial data, you will see the total mass according to your method change.

Comment: Also, you are correct about why the solution becomes unstable.  But the mass according to my method will still be conserved.  You will only observe this mass changing when the solution gets really big (e.g. some data points are $10^{10}$.

Comment: If you want to avoid instability, use a Crank-Nicolson scheme.

Comment: Ok, so if implement first order accurate boundary conditions $(m_1-m_0)/h=0$, i.e. instead of the line $\text{A(1,2)=2*p; A(end,end-1)=2*p;}$ I have $\text{A(1,1)=1-p; A(end,end)=1-p;}$ then it works fine. Do you have an idea why is this? Do you think there must be something wrong with the above method or is a first order scheme with 2nd order boundary conditions "not compatible"?

Comment: For the problem you are trying to model, what is cpnserved is $\int_0^1 m(t,x) \, dx$.  So if you use a first order approximation to solve the equation, you would expect a first order approximation to the mass to be conserved.  Similarly, if you use a second order approximation to solve the equation, you would expect a second order approximation to the mass to be conserved.  The trapezoidal formula is a second order approximation to the integral (after dividing by $M$ of course).  Your approximation - the Riemann sum - is only a first order, because you give too much weight to the end points.